# how to display laravel collection entries next to each other

Tags: html, laravel

im trying to make my collection in laravel to display as so

```
   1       2

   3       4
```

With each one showing a unique entry.

However the entries displayed show a unique entry on every row rather than the way i intended it to do so and displays like so:

```
  1         1

  2         2
```

this is my code:

```
@forelse ($properties as $property)
                    <div class="mt-4 lg:gap-6 lg:flex lg:items-center lg:flex-wrap lg:mt-20">
                        <div class="p-4 bg-white rounded-lg">
                                    <div class="p-6">
                                        <h4 class="text-2xl font-bold cursor-pointer">
                                            {{$property->address1}}
                                            @if(!$property->address2==null)
                                            ,<br/>{{$property->address2}}
                                            @endif
                                        </h4>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <span class="text-xl font-extrabold text-blue-600">@money($property->valuation, 'ZAR')</span> /M
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex mt-2">
                                            Tenant<br>
                                            {{$property->user->name}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex justify-between p-4 text-gray-700 border-t border-gray-300">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-4 bg-white rounded-lg">
                                    <div class="p-6">
                                        <h4 class="text-2xl font-bold cursor-pointer">
                                            {{$property->address1}}
                                            @if(!$property->address2==null)
                                            ,<br/>{{$property->address2}}
                                            @endif
                                        </h4>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <span class="text-xl font-extrabold text-blue-600">@money($property->valuation, 'ZAR')</span> /M
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex mt-2">
                                            Tenant<br>
                                            {{$property->user->name}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex justify-between p-4 text-gray-700 border-t border-gray-300">
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @empty
                    No Properties to show
                @endforelse
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I had to edit the html on stackoverflow because it was not letting me post it. so some of the information called may not match exactly here but they match exactly on my code

Comment: _Sidenote_: `<div>` is not allowed inside `<tr>`, redo your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet and it will output `1 2 3 4` right. Please consider your HTML part based on this.

Controller:

```
$properties = collect([1,2,3,4]);
```

Blade:

```
<link href="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
@forelse ($properties as $index=>$property)
    @if ($index % 2 == 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{$property}}
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="col">
            {{$property}}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@empty
    No Properties to show
@endforelse
```

Alternatively you can use laravel [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable

```
<link href="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
@forelse (collect([1,2,3,4]) as $property)
    @if ($loop->odd)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{$property}}
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="col">
            {{$property}}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@empty
    No Properties to show
@endforelse
```

You can check Live demo [here](https://5esyk.ciroue.com/)